# How to bevel or Round those edges?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges, bevel

i got this model from Turbosquid. The Camera on the backside is not round like the original. This was made in 3DS Max with the hypersmooth modifier. Beveling those edges is nearly impossible, even with the bevel modifier. Is there anotherway to round those edges? Or remove the sharpness in rendering?[image: Rendered image]

---

[image: Render with Subsurf Artifacts]
[image: Editor View]
The Blue Part should fill the whole Lens Area and there are some strange Spikes

Comment: Can't you remodel those parts from scratch?

Comment: Does a subdivision surface modifier deform it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a low-poly mesh, as the camera is not the only thing that isn't nicely subdivided. Allen Simpson recommended the Subdivision Surface modifier, and I agree: "hypersmooth" sounds like basically the same thing.

If you have problems with parts of the mesh shrinking up, try the bevel modifier with an angle limit. Be sure to turn off "clamp overlap" at first so you can see what you're doing.

Comment: Subdivision Modifier don´t fix this. Maybe I play around with the bevel modifier again. Should I use the subdivision Modifier before? And I may remodel this part.

Comment: With Subsurface Modifier (Catwalk-Clark) it's now getting smooth but I get some Artifacts. With the simple Subsurface everything stays the same. Some Pictures are in the Answer below.

Comment: Yeah, was concerned that might happen. Hmm, if only the subsurf could be set not to pull in open edges... I still recommend trying the bevel modifier. use the "percentage" setting so the bevel size will be contextually correct, and set it to about 50%, turning off clamp overlap.

Comment: I solved it, i split the mesh based on the applied Materials and than used the subsurf on every object. And that way the glass was Smoothed the way i wanted.